# Why does this implementation of a thread work without a run method?

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, java-threads

I have received some code through a school project and I'm failing to understand the purpose of the use of threading in this scenario. The project requires use of a multi threading server to pass. I have the following thread implementation which of a new instance is created every time a new client connects.

The problem is that they are not using the run-method, in my understanding the thread exists when it finishes running the run-method. But even after the thread should have finished running it manages to send further the messages from the propertyStateListener. Why does this work and does this really count as a multi-threaded server?

Starts an instance of the ClientHandler every time a new client connects:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        MessageProducer mp;
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new ClientHandler(socket).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The actual `ClientHandler`:

```java
private class ClientHandler extends Thread implements PropertyChangeListener {
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream ois;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private Message messagerecieved;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        messageManager.registerListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        messagerecieved = (Message) evt.getNewValue();
        try {
            oos.writeObject(messagerecieved);
            oos.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Comment: `messageManager `, I'm guess is what's calling the `propertyChange` method of the `ClientHandler` (via `messageManager.registerListener(this);`).  As too wether this is multi-thread would depend on `messageManager`, as they are, as you say, not making use of the `Thread` itself.  As a side note, it's not recommend to extend directly from `Thread` an instead rely on `Runnable`

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The `ClientHandler` is a `Thread` which start through calling the `start` method. This starts the thread and it will execute the code in the `run` method. So yes it is multithreaded as each connection has its own thread.

Comment: @M.Deinum But based on the posted code, there is nothing in the `run` method, yes, it will be executed, but it will immediately exit and the thread will stop. It would seem that the `messageManager` is been used to monitor changes to some state, via the `PropertyChangeListener`, which would mean `ClientHandler` could continue writing to the `Socket` long after `run` has exited, which would not be consider (IMHO) a good thing, based on the intended design.  Maybe if the `propertyChange` method was placing messages into a queue which `run` was then process, it would be multi threaded

Comment: @user3313308 Is the `run` method of `ClientHandler` truely empty?  Also, what is `messageManager`?  Coding conventions suggest that it's a variable, but I don't see it declared anywhere? Either this won't compile or `messageManager.registerListener` is a `static` method.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The run method is definitely empty. Regarding the MessageManager class I failed to explain properly that ClientHandler is an inner class of a class that has a MessageManager declared. The MessageManager class simply calls the PropertyStateListeners when it has a new message.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that the reason the ClientHandler still can be called upon even after the thread has finished running is because it is just another class and even if the thread exists the class and methods still exist to be called upon?

Comment: The `Thread` here is a total red herring. There is nothing useful achieved by making `ClientHandler` extend `Thread`. Remove the `extends Thread`, remove the `run()` method, remove the `.start()`: this will behave just the same. (Or, at least, it should, unless there is some weirdness going on in the manager which requires it to be a `Thread` and a `PropertyChangeListener`)

Comment: @user3313308 `messageManager` is maintaining a strong reference to the class (via it's listener list), so, yes, it's just another class.  The `propertyChange` method will be getting called within what ever context `messageManager` is using to dispatch the events

Comment: @AndyTurner Indeed, even after removing everything thread-related it worked just as well.

Comment: Thank you everyone for a lot of great answers. I was hoping you could answer a last question: When I print out the thread name in the propertyChange method above I get somethin like this: 
Thread-3
Thread-3
Thread-5
Thread-5
Thread-6
Thread-6
Thread-7
Thread-7
Thread-8
Thread-8
And so on as long as the application runs. Even after I remove the thread-logic @AndyTurner suggested. 

Any idea why? And why 2 of every thread?

Comment: Your last question cannot be answered without looking at the entire application.  My guess is that each "request" is changing two properties ... or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that they are not using the run-method, in my understanding the thread [exits] when it finishes running the run-method. But even after the thread should have finished running it manages to send further the messages from the propertyStateListener.

You are correct that the code is confusing for sure.  They are creating a thread with each instance of `ClientHandler` but there is no `run()` method so the thread immediately exits after `start()` is called.  The code would actually still work if `ClientHandler` did not extend thread.

> Why does this work

It is the `messageManager` thread which is calling back to the `ClientHandler.propertyChange(...)` method which writes the results back to the socket, not the `ClientHandler` thread.

> does this really count as a multi-threaded server?

There certainly are 2 threads at work here because you have the socket-accept thread and the `messageManager` thread.  Whether or not this is a "multi-threaded server" depends on the assignment I guess.  Certainly if there was supposed to be a thread per client then this code does not do that.